# Ripple effect in RecyclerView item without postOnAnimationDelayed

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

My items are not showing the Ripple Effect when I click in any recyclerView item if I don't add this code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(final RecyclerView parent, final View view, final int position, final long id)
    ViewCompat.postOnAnimationDelayed(parent, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your click code goes here
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

I got this code from here: [RIpple effect on RecyclerView not working on light tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998374/ripple-effect-on-recyclerview-not-working-on-light-tap)

Without that code if I keep pressing the animation appears, it is just dissapearing with single taps.

BTW, this is only a patch that is slowing the app.

EDIT: my recyclerview is inside a fragment.

Is there a way to fix this problem without it?

Comment: Shot in the dark but its happened to me before. You dont have animations turned off or sped up in the developer settings of the device do you?

Comment: @Devsil nop, all options by default, the rest of animations are working perfectly.

Comment: Have you added this in your xmls - `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground`

Comment: Yes, the ripples appears if I use postanimation. The problem is if I don't use it, the action stops the animation. Is there a way that animation keeps running at same time that the action is triggered and is running?