# Ripple effect for RecyclerView doesn't show on simple clicks

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a **RecyclerView** in my app and i set background properties to its relative layout for **ripple effect**. Ripple shows, but only when i tap and hold, or when i touch and move finger a bit (when it's focused).
On a simple click however, (which opens a new activity) ripple doesn't show.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998374/ripple-effect-on-recyclerview-not-working-on-light-tap) answer which adds a delay of 50ms but it is not ideal.
A couple of other such questions do not have satisfactory answers either.
Apps like YouTube and Whatsapp show a ripple and then open the screen. Do they use delay too?

these are the attributes i set to the relative layout for ripple:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

this is the onclick method (starts a new activity):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyler);
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener
            (new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position){                     
                 String selection = menuDataSet[position];
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 openScreenFromMenu(position);
                }
```

Is there a good way to show ripple on simple clicks too? (without using delay)

Comment: Try removing the foreground attribute. I haven't had any issues with setting the background, clickable, and focusable as you have it here.

Comment: Removing foregroud is making no difference.

Comment: Are you navigating away from the RecyclerView on click?

Comment: One other difference I see from what I'm doing is I'm setting an `onClickListener` to the view in the adapter rather than using the RecyclerView's `onItemTouchListener`.